# raw html in a vue js component (with nuxt)

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I receive inside the object passed in my component a body (actu.body) with html tags inside (mostly p tags) and im wondering how to interpret them for the client side, my code is like that for now :

```
<template>
  <div>
  <!-- {{ actu }} -->
  <v-parallax
    :src="actu.images[0].url"
    dark
  >
  <v-layout
    align-center
    column
    justify-center
  >
  <h1 class="display-2 font-weight-thin mb-3">{{ actu.headline }}</h1>
    <h4 class="subheading">{{ actu.summarry }}</h4>
  </v-layout>
  </v-parallax>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      {{ actu.body }}
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
props: {
actu: {
  type: Object,
  required: true
}
```

}
   };

is there a proper way to do that with vue js ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have a look at the official guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

the trick is the v-html directive

```
<span v-html="rawHtml"></span>
```

Comment: when I run ``npm run lint``, warning appears ``warning  'v-html' directive can lead to XSS attack  vue/no-v-html``

Comment: yes thats right, and this is also documented in the docs from vue. So you should only use this if you can trust the source and never put in there user content.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

```
<v-card-text v-html="actu.body"></v-card-text>
```